# YAML Anchor and Aliases in Selenium grid helm chat is displayed verbatim in helm install dry run

Tags: kubernetes-helm, selenium-grid

I am working on the helm chart provided for the selenium grid . I can see YAML Anchors and aliases are used here .

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/trunk/charts/selenium-grid/templates/chrome-node-deployment.yaml#L7

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/trunk/charts/selenium-grid/templates/chrome-node-deployment.yaml#L25

however when i use  helm install dry run, these anchors are displayed verbatim in the genearated manifest :

```
-helm install --namespace selenium-spot --debug --dry-run guava ./charts/selenium-grid/
```

```
metadata:
  name: selenium-chrome-node
  namespace: selenium-spot
  **labels: &chrome_node_labels**
    app: selenium-chrome-node
    app.kubernetes.io/name: selenium-chrome-node
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: helm
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: guava
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 4.8.1-20230221
    app.kubernetes.io/component: selenium-grid-4.8.1-20230221
    helm.sh/chart: selenium-grid-0.15.3
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: selenium-chrome-node
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: guava
  template:
    metadata:
      **labels: *chrome_node_labels**
```

is there any secondary rendering happening which i am not able to see here ? Am i missing anything hereI am expecting the anchor `"&"` to copy all the values beneath it and the alias `"*"` to insert it wherever it is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of a Helm chart is plain text that happens to parse as YAML.  Beyond some validation that the resulting document is in fact valid YAML, Helm does not parse and reserialize it; what you get is the actual output of the templates.  Even without using YAML anchors you can see differences in inline *vs.* block lists, indentation, and extra blank lines, and these will be faithfully reproduced in the output even though they don't matter to the YAML serialization.

In my experience, YAML anchors aren't really idiomatic in Helm charts, particularly since the same block could be repeated across multiple files.  It's more common to write a helper template

```yaml
{{/* _helpers.tpl */}}

{{- define "mychart.labels" -}}
app: selenium-chrome-node
app.kubernetes.io/name: selenium-chrome-node
et: cetera
{{ end -}}
```

And then you can include that template everywhere it appears, even if that's in multiple files.

```yaml
{{/* deployment.yaml */}}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
{{ include "mychart.labels" . | indent 4 }}
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
{{ include "mychart.labels" . | indent 8 }}
```

Comment: (Rarely directly relevant, but a [YAML alias](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#3222-anchors-and-aliases) does not actually create a copy of the referenced anchor; instead, it creates a second reference to the anchor note in the representation graph.  But this doesn't matter to most uses of anchors, only if you're manipulating parsed YAML in code.)